# mostrar ultimo registro de una tabla en c# con sql server

Tags: c#, sql

Lo que intento hacer es capturar el ultimo codigo que se ingreso de mi tabla en sql y mostrarlo en mi txt que esta en c# 
intente con este codigo  pero no me funciono espero su ayuda

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexion"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select Nro_Pedido from pedido where nro_pedido= (select @@IDENTITY)", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader nro = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (nro.Read())
            {
                txtnum_ped.Text = nro["Nro_pedido"].ToString();

            }
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Tienes algún campo en tu tabla que registre la fecha de ingreso? Porque si es así, podrías realizar un `orderBy desc` por esa fecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo hice lo mismo con la ID_Venta y así obtiene el ultimo y solo le sume 1 y para  una nueva venta.

```
**
String id_ultima = "SELECT distinct TOP 1 (ID_Ventas) FROM TablaVentas ORDER BY ID_Ventas DESC";
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=XtremeFoodV2;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand ejecutar = new SqlCommand(id_ultima, Con);
    Con.Open();
    SqlDataReader leer = ejecutar.ExecuteReader(); 
    if (leer.Read() == true)
    {
        ultimo = Convert.ToInt32(leer["ID_Ventas"].ToString());
        ultimo++;
        Con.Close();
    }
```

**

Espero te sirva.Por cierto, esto se puede causar un error si en dado caso tu tabla este vacía, ya que obtendrá un valor null y no le podrá sumar 1, lo que puedes hacer para solucionarlo es agregar un registro vació para que inicie en 0 o poner por default en tu base de datos el valor 0.

Comment: Gracias si me funciono

Answer (score 0):

esto no es de sql server pero puede que sirva
select pagoresultado from pagoparcial WHERE idsociopp = '" + searchnombre + "' ORDER BY idpagoparcial DESC LIMIT 1";